# i want to make time picker like iphone in android

Tags: android

I want to create a time picker in android that should be similar to iphone's time picker i.e vertical slider.
what should I do? will it be some custom component? if yes than how?

Answer (score 3):

Try Android Wheel http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Comment: I am unable to use this wheel. kindly suggest some good tutorial